# Error when installing Galago

Tags: java, maven, lemur

Hi i want to install Galago from the netbeans IDE or from the Promt command line with mvn package
I installed maven

But when i run build with dependency, i have this error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project tupleflow-gridengine: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.lemurproject.galago:tupleflow-gridengine:jar:3.10: Could not find artifact org.ggf.drmaa:drmaa:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

In the build instructions it tells you to run a script first. This dependency is unavailable on maven central so the jar is in the source distribution.

```
./scripts/installib.sh
# now recompile
mvn install
```